# Import Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datapump, impdp, imp

I want to import a `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

using the command :

```
impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:"IN ('IMMBO')"
```

But I got this error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39145: directory object parameter must be specified and non-null
```

Do I have to first create the log file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide value for Directory parameter.

```
impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO 
    DIRECTORY=TEST_Dir            <-- You need to provide value for this param
    DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp 
    LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log 
    REUSE_DATAFILES=YES 
    exclude=tablespace:"IN ('IMMBO')"
```

Where `TEST_Dir` is a Directory object in Oracle, that points to a location where the file is, from where the data is being imported.

## Example:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY Test_Dir AS 'C:\TestFolder';
```

Also make sure to give Read, Write permissions to user on that Directory.

```
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY Test_Dir TO UserName;
```

Comment: to exectue the create directory I had to connect as sysdb like this `connect sys/password as sysdba` and then to physicaly create the directory with